# Time Slot from df in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, timeslots

I'm trying to create time slot starting from time column in my df which have the following structure:

```
artist_name;ms_played;track_name;...date;time;week_day
Taylor Swift;35260;Wildest Dreams;...;2021-01-25;07:55;0
Edward Sharpe & The Magnetic Zeros;...2021-01-25;15:34;0
.....
```

for example, all time between 6am and 8am I want it to fall within the time slot 6-8 and so on for the others. So far I have unfortunately not been able to write anything, so any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Do you want to create a new column called 'time slot'? based on value of time?

Comment: yes this is what I would like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with the help of the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Taylor Swift','Edward Sharpe & The Magnetic Zeros'],'time':['7:55','15:34']})

def timeSlot(x):
    hr = pd.to_datetime(x).hour
    if hr == 23:
        upper = 0
        lower = hr-1
    elif hr == 0:
        upper = hr+1
        lower = 23
    else:
        upper = hr+1
        lower = hr-1
    return f'{lower}-{upper}'
df['slot'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: timeSlot(x))
```

Comment: thx, this is what i was looking for